# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS libusb/hidapi fails to open Corsair/Elgato Streamdeck

Tags: usb, udev

I'm trying to use the following library for interfacing with the corsair streamdeck on linux: https://github.com/dh1tw/streamdeck

It works perfectly with sudo, but does not work with a regular user.

When I try and run it without sudo it fails to open the device.

```
hidapi: failed to open device
```

I created a `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-usb-streamdeck.conf` with the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fd9", ATTR{idProduct}=="0060", GROUP="plugdev", TAG+="uaccess"
```

I've added my user to the `plugdev` group but it still fails to open the device.

I reloaded rules, logged off/in, restarted but it still wont let me interface with this device.

The vendor/product id are as follows:

```
// VendorID is the USB VendorID assigned to Elgato (0x0fd9)
const VendorID = 4057

// ProductID is the USB ProductID assigned to Elgato's Stream Deck (0x0060)
const ProductID = 96
```

Can anyone spot whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to the rule I created ending with `.conf` instead of `.rules`.

... Dammit